# Writing unsigned char into an output file

Tags: c++, file, unsigned

this might be a simple question but I'm not sure why I'm not getting it right. 
I have unsigned char buf of which I need to write its data to an output file f_out. when I write as following:

```
f_out << buf;
```

I get correct data.

However I want to write the data line by line, 32 bit (char) in a line as the data is binary numbers. I have used the following but I got totally different data:

```
for (int i = 1; i < Buff_size; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 32; j++) {
            f_out << buf[i];
        }
        f_out << endl;
    }
```

Comment: What's the encoding used?

Comment: This loop `for (int j = 1; j <= 32; j++) { f_out << buf[i]; }` will write each `buf[i]` **32 times** - is that what you want?

Comment: Oh yeah, now I see what I did there :) I have fixed and it is working now! Many thanks. 
for (int i = 0; i <= Buff_size; i++) {
   f_out << buf[i];
   j=j+1;
   if (j==33) {
    j = 1;
    f_out << endl;
   }
  }
This is what I meant!

Comment: @MHDAnasAlsakkal you have a buffer overflow. You need to use `<` instead of `<=` in your loop. Also, you can use the `%` operator instead of the `j` variable. Though, I would use a completely different kind of logic: `int loops = Buff_size / 32; int offset = 0; for (int i = 0; i < loops; ++i, offset += 32) { f_out.write(&buf[offset], 32); f_out << endl; } int remaining = Buff_size % 32; f_out.write(&buf[offset], remaining);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code as you have it, the following loop:

```cpp
for (int j = 1; j <= 32; j++) {
    f_out << buf[i];
}
```

will write each element of the array **32 times** on each line!

If what you want to do is to write each element **only once** but so that there are 32 elements per line, you need something like this:

```cpp
int i, j;
for (i = 0, j = 0; i < Buff_size; i++) {
    f_out << buf[i];
    if (++j == 32) { // 32 done ...
        f_out << endl; // ... write newline
        j = 0;         // ... and reset count
    }
    else f_out << " "; // Stay on same line - but insert a space
}
if (j != 0) f_out << endl; // If we have 'leftover' buffer
```

Feel free to ask for further explanation and/or clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I have got the question. There are multiple problems in your code:

(1) You skipped the buf[0], which means the first byte is not written to the file.

(2) You are writing the same byte for 32 times.

Is that what you expect? I guess the second codes should be updated to :

```
assert(Buff_size%32 == 0)
for (int i = 0; i < Buff_size/32; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
            f_out << buf[i*32 + j];
        }
        f_out << endl;
}
```